# Adjusting size of plot in Matlab so that graph does not get cut off by edge of plot window

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I've created a plot in Matlab, but unfortunately the side of the plot is cut off by the plotting window.  Here is the code that I've used to create the plot:

```
% create a plot with dots and with bold sides
point = num(:, 1);
depth = num(:, 2);
hfig = plot(point, depth, '-s', 'Color', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerSize', 10);

% make the outside of the graph bold
set(gca, 'LineWidth', axis_size);
set(gca,'FontSize', ticksize, 'FontName', fontname);
set(gca, 'Position', [0.2 0.2 0.8 0.4])
xlabel('Point Number')
ylabel('Depth (cm)')
```

Here is the output:

[image: Cutoff image]

Notice how the side of the plot has been cut off.  Alternately, here is a picture showing what I want to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

I simply created the plot without the call to `set(gca, 'Position', [0.2 0.2 0.8 0.4])`, and then resized the plot by resizing the window.

But how do I do this in code? I also want to ensure that I can save out the plot as a PNG file with the same dimensions.  I've been playing around with various combinations of the `set()` function, and I've been unable to attain what I want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following document ([How to produce figures with Matlab that have the right dimensions when printed](http://itb.biologie.hu-berlin.de/~schaette/HomeFiles/MatlabPlots.pdf)) provides some example code that can be used to resize the plot in the proper fashion.

The following code was used:

```
point = num(:, 1);
depth = num(:, 2);

hfig = plot(point, depth, '-s', 'Color', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerSize', 10);
set(gca, 'LineWidth', axis_size);
set(gca,'FontSize', ticksize, 'FontName', fontname);
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters')
xSize = 30; ySize = 5;
xLeft = (21-xSize)/2; yTop = (30-ySize)/2;
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[xLeft yTop xSize ySize])
set(gcf,'Position',[300 600 xSize*50 ySize*50])

xlabel('Point Number');
ylabel('Depth (cm)');
```

Here is a picture of the result.  This looks similar to the one that I posted in my question above.  I don't know if this is dependent on monitor size and/or screen resolution.

[image: Expected result]

Comment: This is the solution that I am using for the time being, but Xurtio and Andrey's solutions are good as well.  Thank you to everyone for responding!

Answer (score 5):

Try to set the `OuterPosition` of the plot.

```
set(gca,'OuterPosition',[0.2 0.2 0.8 0.4]);
```

The image below shows the difference between the two:

[image]

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#OuterPosition) is the relevant MathWorks help page.

Comment: Thank you; this is very much appreciated!  I am still finding it a bit challenging to set the `Position` and the `OuterPosition` of the plot, since whatever I get is still cut off.  Could you suggest some values that I can use to properly resize my plot?

Answer (score 1):

Andrey has the simplest answer, but alternatively (and for the long term) you can go to the file exchange and download subaxis.m, which replaces subplot, and is superb for even single axes plots (you can define properties like LeftMargin and RightMargin and PaddingTop and PaddingBottom)

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot