# Display a plot without the figure getting compressed in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a MATLAB code where I am generating a boundary figure for some word from an image.
This is then plotted using points generated from `bwboundaries` function and then I am using the generated plot to create an image that I am using later on in the code.

Here is the code snippet:

```
%GET 8-NEIGHBOURHOOD BOUNDARIES
[B,L,N] = bwboundaries(z,'noholes');

%PLOT THE BOUNDARY FIGURE FOR EACH WORD
figure;
hold on;
for k=1:length(B),
    boundary = B{k};
    if(k > N)
        plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
    else
        plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',2);
    end
    set(gca, 'visible', 'off');
    F = getframe(gcf);
    [X, Map] = frame2im(F);
end
```

Now, with a normal text with a slightly larger font size, I am getting perfect results, as expected. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrJRe.jpg) for proper output.

Now, the moment my font size is slightly smaller or the letters are a bit closely spaced, I find that the generated plot is somehow "squeezed" to fit the window size. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5fW2.jpg) for the wrong output.

I want the plot to take up as much space as it needs to show the entire boundary image, resizing itself if needed.
Otherwise, the `frame2im` is capturing the completely wrong image which is messing up my further computation.

**EDIT**

I must mention that the final plot figure is being formed by appending several smaller plots into one figure. This final plot is then being converted using `frame2im`.
As each smaller plot is being "appended", the rest of the image "squeezes" itself to make room for newer plots. Thus, the final image is totally squished together.

---

I thought that [Adjusting size of plot in Matlab so that graph does not get cut off by edge of plot window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723072/adjusting-size-of-plot-in-matlab-so-that-graph-does-not-get-cut-off-by-edge-of-p) was a possible duplicate, but in that particular case, the plot was getting truncated. In my case, I find the plot getting "squeezed" to fit the area.

Comment: can you do something like a print to png and then read that back in to get the image? something like `print -dpng image.png; imread(image.png)`

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted to avoid. I will essentially create more than a thousand images each time, maybe more. So you can understand my hesitation.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 The issue is not with saving the plot as png.
The issue is that the plot itself is getting squeezed to fit the area. So even if I save as png, it will still be the squeezed image.

Comment: oh ok, I did not know whether the problem was sourced from the `frame2im` command. I have never used it before, so I was unsure. just a guess :)

Comment: @MZimmerman6
Even I don't really know what the issue is exactly. :)
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but it may help.
Here goes a test

```
%Simulation of a binary L and proper visualization
A=zeros(100,100);
A(80:90,10:60)=1;
A(10:90,10:20)=1;
figure,imagesc(A)

% concatenation of 20 binary L's and the shrink visualization
num=20;
A2=repmat(A,1,num);
figure,
imagesc(A2)

%correction of the visualization through the definition of the axes dimensions
figure,
axes('unit','normalized','position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8/10])
imagesc(A2)

%correction of the visualization through the definition of the axis dimensions
figure,
imagesc(A2)
axis ([0,1000,0,100]) % axis image
```

You can use this templates to change the appearance of your image and therefore correct the shrinking.